# GetUserProfilePropertyFor(Manager) differs from the managers Account

Tags: rest, user-profile, user-profile-property

I will explain how I am currently doing my REST calls, by the hyperlinks.

```
_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$select=Account&$filter=substringof('Joe',Name)
_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountname=@v, propertyname='Manager')?@v='i:0#.w|domain\joe.wallis'
_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$select=Id&$filter=Account eq 'domain\Jane.doe'
```

- First off I get my account name,
  then I proceed to get my managers ID via their account name,
  but their `Account` is `i:0#.w|domain\Jane.doe`,
  not `domain\Jane.doe`, which is returned from `GetUserProfilePropertyFor`.
- I can't use `$filter=substringof('domain\Jane.doe',Account)` as it will return `domain\Jane.doe2` along with `domain\Jane.doe.admin`.
- If I could just do `GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountname=@v, propertyname='ManagerId')`,
  it would solve this all, but as far as I know there is no such URL.
- And finally, I would prefer to have a method that can be converted to office 365 with ease.
  And so doing `$filter=substringof('i:0#.w|{Manager}',Account)` would not work.

But I understand beggars can't be choosers.

---

I'm using Angular.js and so my AJAX requests are different to JQuery.
The headers for my AJAX calls are:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-RequestDigest'] =
    document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
```

Where the AJAX calls are:

```
var search = 'Joe';

$http.get(
    _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList' +
    "?$select=Account&$filter=substringof('" + search + "',Name)"
).then(getManagerAccount);

function getManagerAccount(response) {
    $http.get(
        _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
        '/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/' +
        "GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountname=@v, propertyname='Manager')?@v='" +
        encodeURIComponent(response.data.d.results[0].Account) + "'"
    ).then(getManagerId);
}

function getManagerId(response) {
    $http.get(
        _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList' +
        "?$select=Id&$filter=Account eq '" +
        encodeURIComponent(response.data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor) + "'"
    ).then(function (response) {
        response = response.data.d.results[0];
        if (response) {
            alert(response.Id);
        } else {
            alert("Could not get the manger's ID.");
        }
    });
}
```

---

In short is there any way to get the correct `manager Id` from either a *user* `Account` or `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually retrieving represents the claims-aware user identifier which in your case, because it is for Windows (i:0#.w part), which in SharePoint 2013 is the native one (unless you have created specifically your web app using Classic - that you shouldn't). One can convert between classic login and claims-aware, example here http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/.

To understand how this work please consult http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx. Obviously the simplest would be split string, but not recommended as multiple authentication providers could be configured and each will have a different prefix.

Also, I could notice you are relying on the User information List which might not be a good idea because that Identifier is specific to each Site collection (unless that is what you are chasing).